# How remove background from -moz-appearance button

Tags: html, css, firefox

on my page I added `select` component and on the Firefox I have problem with select button. On the Chrome I have normal arrow down like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9f4t.png)
but on Firefox button look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8pxD.png). How I can remove background on Firefox?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using a custom arrow. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript). Hope that helps.